# How to properly use create event in google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script

Lets say we have this code:

```
var data1 = "2021-05-09"
var data2 = "19:00"
var data3 = "Gym"
//next is create event
```

How my create event should look like? And what your suggestions? Is there a way combine to variables?

Answer (score 0):

That question is very basic, as it is unclear what exactly you want to do. Assuming you want to create a `CalendarEvent` you are missing one piece of information, namely the `End Time` and perhaps which `Calendar` you want to place the `Event`, in case you have multiple `Calendars` . You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date)) for an explanation of how to create an event, e.g.

```
// prepare your variable
 const startDateTime = new Date(data1+"T"+data2)
 const durationInMinutes = 30 // you can customize this
 const endDateTime = new Date(startDateTime.getTime() + (1000*60*60*durationInMinutes) )
 const eventTitle = data3

// Creates an event and log Id
  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
               .createEvent(eventTitle, startDateTime, endDateTime);

Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```

And you should read into what a `Date` Object [is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: i want do do event using variables, not writing each time new date and hour, using variable would give me a way to automate it

Comment: Please see the code now about how you can go about it. Basically the variables need to be of the type `DateTime` in order to be understood. The current example should take the time zone into account in which your apps script project runs, but you should test this yourself to verify.